# Why do socks in a ball separate in the washing machine?

Tags: everyday-life, entropy

When I take a pair of socks off I bundle the two socks together into a ball.

I then put many pairs into the washing machine and when the cycle is finished they are all separated.

For me to separate the two socks seems to require more than just energy; it requires an intelligent way of separating them. How does the  washing machine achieve this?

Comment: It wets the socks and then throws them around. You could experiment with doing the same manually, and see how much (or little) thinking is required. (+1)

Comment: Spinning at 1000 rpm will separate a lot of things, especially soap covered socks.

Comment: In winter I'd often wear two pair of socks and being a guy, I'd just pull off the 2 pairs together and put them in my laundry.   They'd often remain like that after washing and drying.    I've never washed socks in a ball though.

Comment: Just thought this might put your sock problem in perspective, a cat survives 2 minutes in a washing machine : http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-nottinghamshire-36912549

Answer (score 3):

This depends on how well you tie them together.  If you tie them strongly, it is unlikely that they will get separated.  If you put one deep inside the other, it does not normally get separated (if they are long socks).  I normally do the latter.

When the washing machine is quickly spinning in one direction, then all the clothes stick to the inside walls of the machine, due to the centrifugal force.  However, the clothes will 'jumble' around when:

(1) the machine is not spinning fast enough to provide enough centrifugal force for all the clothes to 'stick' to the walls.

(2) The spin direction reverses. I have noticed that most washing machines reverse their spin directions a couple of times.

I guess that these above processes, together with some soapy water can separate at least some pairs of not-too-well tied socks.